# Preventing XSS attacks in C# MVC4

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4, xss

I have the following controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Reset(FormCollection form)
    {
        string[] userName = form.GetValues("username");

        Models.HomeModel hm = new Models.HomeModel();

        //Check this map exists, as in the user actual exists
        //at all.
        if (!hm.UserExists(userName[0]))
            return View("Index");

        if (hm.CheckForExistingLink(userName[0]))
            return View("LinkExists");

        if (hm.CreateLink(userName[0]))
            return View("Success");
        else
            return View("UnSuccessful");

    }
```

If the user enters `<b>` as the username then it is throwing an application error, what is the simplest way to prevent XSS? I had a look at the Sanitizer AntiXSS but after adding it to the project and seeing it available in the referneces I am still not able to call it

Comment: If you just want the name passing through then add [ValidateInput(false)] on your controller method. You will need to sanitise the input but that is fairly trivial.

Comment: The error message is "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (username="<b>")."

Comment: I have been told not to use ValidateInput(false) on this page and have been told to santise the input but the field userName is a string array and I have beeen had some issues trying to do this. I added the AntiXSS library using NuGet package manager and added the references but it will not find the Sanitize method as per an example I had found

Comment: Have you added a 'Using' for it?

Comment: I have tried adding a using Microsoft.Security.Application.AntiXss.... but this is not being found by intellisense for some reason

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30511/discussion-between-jay-and-rob)